# Intersect возвращает все уникальные значения

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть 2 списка:

1. `List<Product> products1` (6 объектов класса `Product`)
2. `List<Product> products2` (1 объект класса `Product`, также содержащийся в `products1`).

Задача: Из двух списков передать в третий только значения, входящие в оба списка (в данном случае — один объект (например, с ProductId = 1).

Пробую сделать так: `result = products1.Intersect(products2)`. При отладке `result` содержит 6 значений, а должен — 1.

Узнал, что для корректной работы `Intersect` со сложными объектами в них нужно переопределить класс, реализующий интерфейс `IEqualityComparer<>`.

По данному совету создал класс:

```
    public class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
    {
        public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
        {
            return x.ProductId == y.ProductId;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Product product)
        {
            return product.ProductId.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

И добавил его в качестве параметра при сравнении:

```
result = products1.Intersect(products2, new ProductComparer());
```

Тем не менее, на результат это не повлияло. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а [пример из справки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx) верный результат дает?

Comment: @Grundy тот же результат.

Comment: тот же - верный, или тот же - ошибочный?

Comment: @Grundy Пример из справки, предложенный вами, также дает ошибочный результат.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос: минимальную программу которую можно запустить, которую вы запускаете и получаете неверный ответ.

Comment: пример дает верный результат: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0PsQof

Comment: @Grundy в моем случае (скопировал себе в проект ваш пример) duplicates при отладке выдает null. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Пример по приведенной выше ссылке работает? Если да - приведите код программы, которую вы запускаете и проверяете, так же важно в какой момент вы проверяете значение duplicates.

Comment: Получилось! Ваше последнее предложение принесло мне больше всего пользы. Изначальное недоверие к своему коду привело к тому, что я не шел дальше, пока не увижу, что в result лежит правильное значение. Убрав точку остановы и запустив проект, убедился, что запрос дает правильный результат — result соответствует ожиданиям. Остался один вопрос новичка: почему result был неверен в точке его объявления? Это связано с логикой метода? Типа он имитирует цикл, а я его «прозваниваю» в момент объявления, до тела цикла?

Comment: все зависит от места точки остановки: если она стоит на строчке с присваиванием, то да, остановка происходит **до** того как оператор выполнится, следовательно вы видите значение не инициализированной переменной

Comment: @Grundy Понял. Спасибо большое за уделенное время!

Comment: @Grundy _"пример дает верный результат: dotnetfiddle.net/0PsQof"_ -- в примере: `Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null)`, а почему не так `x == null`?

Comment: @Stack, потому что копия примера с msdn - на него ссылка выше есть.

Comment: @Grundy _" потому что копия примера с msdn"_ -- понятно. но проще так `==`, т.к. `Object.ReferenceEquals` вызывает  `==` -- см. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489547/196972)