# Как правильно: Object.ReferenceEquals или Оператор ==?

Tags: c#, .net

Как правильно сравнить два объекта, чтобы определить являются ли экземпляры  объектов одним и тем же экземпляром или нет?
Что правильно/лучше использовать: метод [Object.ReferenceEquals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if(Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)) { /*...*/ }
```

или [Оператор ==](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/53k8ybth.aspx)

```
if(a == b) { /*...*/ }      // object a, b;
```

---

**ВНИМАНИЕ:** не путайте Equals c ReferenceEquals

Comment: Уже было: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454619/10105

Comment: На ту же тему: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/09/double-your-dispatch-double-your-fun/

Comment: @VladD _"Уже было: ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454619/10105"_ -- там другое. сранивают `Оператор ==` и `Object.Equals`. _"На ту же тему: blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/09/…"_ -- тогда в 2009 г. не было открытых исходников .NET и приходилось верить на слово.

Comment: А за что минус? Вопрос хороший.

Comment: @VladD _"Вопрос хороший"_ -- если так, то поставьте плюс)

Comment: Поставил. И ещё минус убрали, судя по всему.

Answer (score 3):

В [исходнике .NET Framework](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/), метод [Object.ReferenceEquals](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,81) определен следующим образом:

```
public static bool ReferenceEquals (Object objA, Object objB) {
    return objA == objB;       
}
```

В методе вызывается `Оператор ==`, значит **если сравнивать Object'ы**, то нет разницы.

---

Реализация [Equals](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,68) следующая

```
public static bool Equals(Object objA, Object objB) 
{
    if (objA==objB) {
        return true;
    }
    if (objA==null || objB==null) {
        return false;
    }
    return objA.Equals(objB);
}
```

**ВНИМАНИЕ**: если `Оператор ==` вернет false, то может быть вызван метод `public virtual bool Equals(Object obj)` -- метод виртуальный, может быть переопределен в производных классах и полагаться на него не надо.

---

Для идентификации можно использовать метод [RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/11tbk3h9(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

if(RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(a) == RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(b)) { /*... */ }
```

**ВНИМАНИЕ:** если `a` и `b` это строки, то RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode для одинаковых строк может вернуть разные хэш-коды.

Например,

```
var s1 = "321";    
var s2 = String.Concat(new List<string> { "3", "2", "1" });
var r1 = s1 == s2;     // true
var r2 = RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(s1) == RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(s2);   // false
```

Дело в том, что литералы (строки, определенные в коде, такие как "321"), добавляются во внутренний пул строк в целях экономии памяти.
А строки, собранные из частей, в пул не добавляются. Поэтому получается, что s1 и s2 - разные объекты.
Но s2 можно интернировать (т.е. добавить в пул строк)

```
s2 = String.Intern(s2);
```

Т.к. в пуле строк уже есть s1, то s2 и s1 будут указывать на один и тот же строковой объект, поэтому хэш-коды у s1 и s2 станут равны.

```
var r3 = RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(s1) == RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(s2); // true
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35377/discussion-on-answer-by-stack---object-referenceequals--).

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, здесь более важна не техническая сторона вопроса, а читабельность кода.

Если у вас есть два объекта `a` и `b`, и вы сравниваете их через `==`, может быть вызван не `operator == (object, object)`, а перегруженный оператор сравнения. Это значит, что семантика `==` шире, чем простое сравнение ссылок.

Если ваша цель — распознать именно один и тот же экземпляр, я бы посоветовал использовать именно `ReferenceEquals`, т. к. при этом вы прямо «говорите» то, что хотите. Преимущество в компактности кода у `==`, на мой взгляд, даёт недостаточный выигрыш по сравнению в преимуществе в понятности кода. Да и для правильности сравнения нужно приведение типа к `object`, которое тоже не добавляет краткости.

---

С другой стороны, если вам нужно установить не равенство *ссылок*, а логическую тождественность объектов, для этого более правильным может оказаться использование (возможно перегруженного) оператора `==`. Поэтому используйте то, что вам нужно. Универсального совета нет, каждый из методов имеет своё применение.

---

Ещё одна техническая деталь — в обобщённых (generic-) методах на текущий момент (C# 6) невозможно сообщить компилятору, что у типа есть оператор `==`. Поэтому сравнение через `==` в generic-методе может дать не такой же результат, как в обычном методе.