# Как работает интернирование строк

Tags: c#, .net, строки, equals

коллеги!

хотела бы спросить вопросы, которые у меня возникли при более подробном изучении языка .NET и трудности касаются как минимум ссылочного типа string

1) Intern pool; ([пулСтрок](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BB_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA))
Позволяет объединить строки с одинаковыми значениями в них в определенный пул памяти. 
В данном случае мы инициализировали две строки с одинаковыми значениями и они попали в один пул памяти. пример в моем понимании:

```
string a = "aaa";
string b = "aaa";
bool c = (object)a == (object) b; // И получаем true
```

ОДНАКО код:

```
string a = "aaa"; 
string b = "aa"; 
b+="a"; 
    bool c = (object)a == (object) b; // И получаем false
```

Почему так? и как это работает? по сути мы получаем строку с одинаковыми значениями и все они должны ссылаться на один объект. почему мы по итогу получаем разные результаты? 
Я понимаю, что в данном случае мы сравниваем объекты, а не содержимое. Но почему они не объединились?

Comment: Поиск строки в пуле — это операция за которую на платить. Не все хотят это делать. Если Вы готовы это делать, то можете вызывать данные операции явно: `string.IsInterned` и `string.Intern`.

Comment: вы не могли бы пояснить что имеете ввиду?

Comment: Предположу, что сравниваются по хешу, который генерируется при создании объекта. Во втором примере у вас объект изменяется. Попробуйте добавить третий вариант с удалением части строки и сравнением. По идее должно быть `true` на выходе.

Comment: "почему они не объединились?" Потому что, в первом случае известно что строка одна на этапе компиляции. А во, втором уже на этапе выполнения программы

Comment: @Rootware объект строки неизменяем

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489546/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-object-referenceequals-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80).

Comment: ну и этот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417843/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-interning-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F

Comment: По дефолту интернируются только **литералы**, строки, которые образовались иным способом, нужно добавлять вручную.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

В первом вашем примере строки интернируются на этапе компиляции. Если посмотреть в утилите ILDASM, то в окне MetaInfo в разделе User Strings будет представлен всего один экземпляр:

```
70000001 : ( 3) L"aaa"
```

Соответственно, обе переменные: и `a`, и `b` будут указывать на этот адрес.

Во втором примере в результате конкатенации тоже получается строка "aaa", но она не заносится по умолчанию в пул интернированных строк, потому что для этого нужны дополнительные проверки, то есть тратится время.

Во втором примере можно добавить строку в пул вручную:

```
string a = "aaa";
string b = "aa";
b += "a";
b = string.Intern(b);
bool c = (object)a == (object)b; // True
```

Ответ на вопрос из комментария:

Я не уверен, но, думаю, выгода в том, что после интернирования переменная `b` станет указывать на тот же участок памяти, что и `a`. После чего сборщик мусора сможет убрать другой экземпляр строки "aaa". Это почти бессмысленно для коротких строк, но может оказаться выгодно для длинных долгоживущих строк.

Также нужно учитывать, что удалить строку из пула невозможно. Она так и будет висеть в памяти до конца работы приложения. Именно поэтому в рантайме строки не добавляются в пул по умолчанию.

Comment: это потрясающий ответ. они неизменяемы во время компиляции явно и , получается, при компиляции мы получаем совершенно иной объект ?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, может лучше тогда объединить две строки в `b = string.Intern(b+= "a");` ? Ну чтобы объект вообще не создавался.

Comment: @Kate - то ли я вас не понял, то ли вы что-то не совсем понимаете. Одинаковые строковые литералы на этапе компиляции будут представлены в одном экземпляре, и далее везде будут использованы ссылки на него. А в рантайме получается другой экземпляр. Естественно, у него другая ссылка.

Comment: @4per - думаю, это ничего не изменит. Новый объект строки все равно будет создан в результате конкатенации. Нужно смотреть IL-код (а мне лень...)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, тогда я не понимаю, где же выгода, от `string.Intern()`

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, да, я именно это и имею ввиду. спасибо!

Comment: @4per - я не уверен, но, думаю, выгода в том, что после интернирования переменная `b` станет указывать на тот же участок памяти, что и `a`. После чего сборщик мусора сможет убрать другой экземпляр строки `"aaa"`. Это почти бессмысленно для коротких строк, но может оказаться выгодно для длинных долгоживущих строк.

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы не гадать, глянем сразу IL-инструкции которые генерирует компилятор:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldstr       "aaa"
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0007:  ldstr       "aaa"
IL_000C:  stloc.1     // b
IL_000D:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_000E:  ldloc.1     // b
IL_000F:  ceq         
IL_0011:  stloc.2     // c
IL_0012:  ldstr       "aaa"
IL_0017:  stloc.3     // a2
IL_0018:  ldstr       "aa"
IL_001D:  stloc.s     04 // b2
IL_001F:  ldloc.s     04 // b2
IL_0021:  ldstr       "a"
IL_0026:  call        System.String.Concat
IL_002B:  stloc.s     04 // b2
IL_002D:  ldloc.3     // a2
IL_002E:  ldloc.s     04 // b2
IL_0030:  ceq         
IL_0032:  stloc.s     05 // c2
IL_0034:  ret
```

Как видим в данном случае в первом блоке мы записали одну и ту же строку в `a`(IL_0006) и `b`(IL_000C), и в данном случае строка является интернированной, во втором же блоке только 'a2'(IL_0017) является интернированной, `b2` после конкатенации (IL_0026) и присваивания (IL_002B) таковой не является.

**UPD:** Следующий код также возвращает `false`:

```
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(b2, a2));
```

Метод `ReferenceEquals` определяет, совпадают ли указанные экземпляры `Object`. 
При сравнении строк. Если `objA` и `objB` являются строками, `ReferenceEquals` возвращает `true` если строки интернированы. Он не выполняет проверку на равенство значений. В следующем примере `s1` и `s2` равны, поскольку они являются двумя экземплярами одной интернированной строки. Тем не менее `s3` и `s4` не равны, поскольку несмотря на то, что они имеют идентичные строковые значения, эти строки не интернированы.

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      String s1 = "String1";
      String s2 = "String1";
      Console.WriteLine("s1 = s2: {0}", Object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2));
      Console.WriteLine("{0} interned: {1}", s1, 
                        String.IsNullOrEmpty(String.IsInterned(s1)) ? "No" : "Yes");

      String suffix = "A";
      String s3 = "String" + suffix;
      String s4 = "String" + suffix;
      Console.WriteLine("s3 = s4: {0}", Object.ReferenceEquals(s3, s4));
      Console.WriteLine("{0} interned: {1}", s3, 
                        String.IsNullOrEmpty(String.IsInterned(s3)) ? "No" : "Yes");
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       s1 = s2: True
//       String1 interned: Yes
//       s3 = s4: False
//       StringA interned: No
```

P.s.:
Метод также возвратит `false` при сравнении типов значений, если `objA` и `objB` являются типами значений, упакованы перед передачей в `ReferenceEquals` и 
 представляют одно и то же значение.

```
int int1 = 3;
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(int1, int1));    //False
Console.WriteLine(int1.GetType().IsValueType);            //True
```

Comment: "Как видим", чтобы видеть надо суметь это прочесть.

Comment: вы не могли бы объяснить немного подробнее?

Comment: Хешкод тут не при чем. Он берется лишь при сравнении по значению, а в примере сравниваются ссылки.